# HTML tag to have image dynamically adjust to fill screen?

Tags: html, xhtml, tags, slideshow

I am learning how to make a slideshow presentation with [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/), and it allows the insertion of images via standard HTML tags.

For slideshows, it is often useful to have a background image that fills the screen during the presentation. Is there a way, such as a HTML tag, that specifically adjusts an image to fill the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the *theme* of the S5 slideshows, see pretty.css at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/filemap.html There are a number of other themes provided on the site. Have you looked at these?

Comment: Yes I have seen this, but I am looking for a solution for a single image in one slide, and not something that applies to a whole theme. Thanks for the tip though!